# Zip With Partial J Flag

Tags: linux, zip

I'm running:

```
zip -r /var/www/html/example.com/temp/test.zip /var/www/html/example.com/files_to_zip/
```

which works but gives me the full directory structure of `/var`. I saw the `-j` flag which removes these directories, but it also removes the directories in `files_to_zip`. Is there a way to recursively build my zip from the `files_to_zip` directory?

I'm running `Amazon Linux 2` and my `zip` is using `Zip 3.0`.

So the previously described behaviors are demonstrated with:

```
exec('zip -r ' . $temp_dir . 'test.zip ' . $zip_dir . '/');
exec('zip -rj ' . $temp_dir . 'test.zip ' . $zip_dir . '/');
```

I've modified my code per the provide dup and answer to:

```
exec('(cd ' . $zip_dir . '; zip -r ' . $temp_dir . 'test.zip ' . $zip_dir . '/)'); 
exec('cd ' . $zip_dir . '; zip -r ' . $temp_dir . 'test.zip ' . $zip_dir . '/');
```

per https://stackoverflow.com/a/1679060/3783243 I also tried:

```
exec('(cd ' . $zip_dir . ' && zip -r ' . $temp_dir . 'test.zip ' . $zip_dir . '/)');
exec('cd ' . $zip_dir . ' && zip -r ' . $temp_dir . 'test.zip ' . $zip_dir . '/');
```

I've also tried a PHP solution to this:

```
chdir($zip_dir);
exec('pwd', $result);
die(print_r($result));
```

which returned the results of `$zip_dir`.

The behavior is the same, my zip has the full path from `/var`. After every code execution the zip size increases by 1 byte though.

Comment: You're still (probably) telling `zip` to use the full path of `zip_dir` -- when the answers here say to `cd` to the parent (as you've almost done in the later examples) and then to use the *relative* directory name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider something like:

```
(cd /var/www/html/example.com; zip -r /var/www/html/example.com/temp/test.zip files_to_zip)
```

Comment: I've tried this but the behavior is the same. I also tried it with the `chdir();` in PHP per the dup but that also behaved the same. I verified with `exec('pwd', $return);` that I was moved to the correct directory as well.

Comment: I'd recommend you show the exact steps you took and their exact results -- in an edit to the question. My answer is the same as the one Stephen linked to, and should work, so something's missing.

Comment: Okay, I've updated the question. Please let me know if there's more details I should provide.

Comment: This behaves as expected in the linux system.